# JMeter test simultaneous users with sequential requests

Tags: jmeter

I have a problem. I would like to do **sequential http request with JMeter** but **with simultaneous users**.

Example : I've got 100 users and at the same time they try to do :

1. Login
2. Do stuff 1
3. Do stuff 2
4. Logout

In this order :

In my results I don't want to have

User 1 do : login, stuff 1, stuff 2, logout,

after that

User 2 do : login, stuff 1, stuff 2, logout, ...

I would like to have **at the same time User 1 and 2 try to login** after that they do their stuff and logout.

So, in my results I can have this **example** :

Login user 1 
Login user 2 
Stuff 1 user 1 
Stuff 2 user 1 
Stuff 1 user 2 
Stuff 2 user 2 
Logout user 2 
Logout user 1

Thanks

Comment: Posted twice, also on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29938010/jmeter-test-simultaneous-users-with-sequential-requests

Answer (score 1):

Although I have a hard time understanding what you exactly want to achieve, I will try to summarise:

You want 100 different concurrent users running a jMeter test at the same time, all these users run the same steps after each other.

That means three things:

1. Build a jMeter test for the steps. (I would [record the steps](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf))
2. Running the test with 100 concurrent users, use ramp-up 0, see: [JMeter concurrent users count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16077262/jmeter-concurrent-users-count) and [JMeter understanding ramp up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17288545/jmeter-understanding-ramp-up)
3. Running the test with 100 different logins, see: [Multiple user logins in jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623489/multiple-user-logins-in-jmeter)

Comment: Agreed that the Op may want to reconsider their requirements.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you are not actually running 100 users simultaneously. Instead, you are trying to execute 1 user for 100 times with different credentials. 
In this case your thread count is 1.

I think you are maintaining the credentials of your user in a different csv then adding that csv into the test plan and selecting option as Stop Thread on EOF=true, then at the thread group level make loop count forever.

This will definitely work and you get the solution as you expected